# How do I show the exact job detail in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

Suppose I run `hadoop jar ... -mapper path_to_a -reducer path_to_b` and its job id is `job_id_xxx`.

Reversely, how can I know get something like `hadoop jar ... -mapper path_to_a -reducer path_to_b` from `job_id_xxx`?

Answer (score 0):

In case the job is still running you could look up the parameters using `ps` as for any shell command.

Comment: Is there a more general way to do that?